# transparent div background without effects other elements in that div

Tags: html, css, frontend

how to make a transparent div background without effects other elements in that div ?

Itried the opacity but the all elements were effected

Comment: Have you tried `background-color: transparent;`

Comment: Actually, the default background setting of divs **is** transparent. What do you really want?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you want. Do you want the background to be slightly transparent (equivalent to opacity more than 0 but less than 1)? Is the background an image or just a plain color?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a matter of background, you could use something like `color: rgba(0,0,0,0)` to get a transparent background. If you need to make also the text inside the div transparent, I think the only thing you can do is to move out the divs from the parent div and play with positioning to get the visual you want.

Answer (score 0):

The `opacity` property will affect the child elements indeed, since they will inherit the same transparency from the parent element (a principle in CSS).

This can be solved with the `rgba` function with the `background-color` property:

```css
.inherited {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.just-parent {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}

p {
  background-color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="inherited">
  Children affected
  <p>A test</p>
</div>

<div class="just-parent">
  Children not affected
  <p>A test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the background of divs **is** transparent by default (?):

```css
.x {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.y {
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">div x</div>
<div class="y">div y (in front of div x)</div>
```